# Forcing an ODE solver to preserve the norm

Tags: ode, stability, scipy, quantum-mechanics

I have an ODE of the form

$$ \frac{dy}{dt} = -i H y \enspace .$$

where $y$ is a complex vector and $H$ is a time dependent Hermitian matrix.

The norm of the solution $y(t)$ at any point in time should be 1, but due to accumulation of small numerical errors it ends up being substantially off.

A solution for this problem that is used by the `qutip` library is to reset the ode solver every so often by normalizing $y$ at some time $t'$ and resuming from that point. Is there a rigorous explanation why this is a good idea (it seems to work in practice)?

Is there a better way? Even better if it does not require a modification of the solver code?

Comment: You want to use an ode solver that is guaranteed to preserve the norm; these are called ["symplectic"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_integrator) or ["geometric"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_integrator) integrators. There's a book by Hairer, Lubich and Wanner that discusses these methods.

Comment: @ChristianClason, you should make this comment into an answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The best approach is to use an ODE solver that is guaranteed to conserve the norm of the initial condition, i.e., for which $\|y_n\| = \|y_0\|$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Such solvers exist, and are called *geometric integrators*, since they preserve geometric properties of the exact solution (in this case, that energy is conserved, i.e., $\frac{d}{dt}\|y(t)\| = 0$). (A special class are *symplectic integrators* for ODE systems arising in Hamiltonian mechanics.)

The simplest such integrator (that is not specific to Hamiltonian systems) is actually a quite standard method, variously referred to as *trapezoidal*, *implicit mid-point*, or *Crank-Nicolson* method. In your case, it amounts to solving in every step the linear system
$$\left(I+\frac{i\,h_n}2 H(t_{n+1})\right) y_{n+1} =  \left(I-\frac{i\,h_n}2 H(t_{n})\right) y_n,$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix and $h_n = t_{n+1}-t_n$ is the current time step length. This method is implicit, but second-order accurate and A-stable. (I don't think there's a first order geometric integrator.) I don't know if it's included in ODEPACK (the basis of scipy's `odeint` routines), but it shouldn't be too hard to implement yourself.

If you want to know more about geometrical integration:

- Probably the most accessible discussion of geometric integration is Chapter 5 in [A. Iserles, *A First Course in the Numerical Analysis of Differential Equations*, 2nd edition, Cambridge University Press, 2008](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/numerical-analysis/first-course-numerical-analysis-differential-equations-2nd-edition).
- The "bible" is of course [E. Hairer, G. Wanner, C. Lubich, *Geometric Numerical Integration*, 2nd edition, Springer, 2006](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F3-540-30666-8) (see Chapter VII.6 for applications in quantum mechanics). There's also a survey article in [Acta Numerica 12, 2003, p. 399-450](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=165633&fileId=S0962492902000144) (here's a [preprint](http://www.math.kit.edu/ianm3/lehre/geonumint2009s/media/gni_by_stoermer-verlet.pdf)), although that seems to focus on second-order ODEs.
- Specifically the application to the Schrödinger equation is discussed in [E. Faou, *Geometric Numerical Integration and Schrödinger Equations*, Zurich Lectures in Advanced Mathematics, EMS, 2012](http://www.ems-ph.org/books/book.php?proj_nr=143).